# for which alpha is the Integral convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence

Let $\alpha>0$ and

$$
f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{(x-1)^{\alpha}}
$$

for $x>1$

i found that for $\int_2^{\infty}f(x) dx$ the integral is convergence for $\alpha > 2$

but for which $\alpha$ is $f(x)$ convergence for $\int_1^2f(x) dx$ and $\int_1^{\infty}f(x) dx$

Comment: one of my problems is clearly around 1

Comment: Hint: $\forall 1\le x\le2,\ {x-1\over 2}\le\ln(x)\le x-1$, and use the previous limitation on $\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\ln(x)$ is eventually smaller than any positive power.

---

We have that $$\int^\infty_1 \frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha} < \sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha}$$

We know that the RHS is convergent for any $\alpha > 1$, because $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^\alpha}$ is convergent and $\ln(x)$ is eventually smaller than any positive power.

Comment: ... and so does $(x-1)^{\alpha}$? I mean, I see this coming into play, but I do not see it coming *crucially* into play.

Comment: i have found that $\frac{\ln x}{(x-1)^{\alpha}} \leq \frac{x-1}{(x-1)^{\alpha}}=\frac{1}{(x-1)^{\alpha-1}}$ but i only know that integral $\int_0^1$ convergence for $\alpha < 2$ not for $\int_1^2$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli  I hope that my edit helps

Comment: @wythagoras I am very sorry: for some reason I read "number" instead of "power". This indoubtedly helps, and it helped back then too (there's a type-o on the LHS). It does not solve the issue around $1$, though.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli It does. Suppose we have $\alpha = 1.0001$.  For sufficiently large $n$ we have $\ln n < n^{0.00009}$, now we can use that. For the $n$ for which it doesn't hold the sum will be finite anyways.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_1^2 \frac{\log x}{(x-1)^{\alpha}}\,dx=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+}\int_{1+\epsilon}^2 \frac{\log x}{(x-1)^{\alpha}}\,dx$$

For $\alpha =1$, the integral clearly diverges logarithmically.

Now, for $\alpha \ne 1$, integration by parts reveals that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{1+\epsilon}^2 \frac{\log x}{(x-1)^{\alpha}}\,dx&=\left(\frac{1}{1-\alpha}(x-1)^{1-\alpha}\log x\right)|_{1-\epsilon}^2-\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\int_{1+\epsilon}^2 \frac{(x-1)^{1-\alpha}}{x} dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}(\log 2-\epsilon^{\alpha}\log(1-\epsilon))-\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\int_{1+\epsilon}^2 \frac{(x-1)^{1-\alpha}}{x} dx
\end{align}$$

The first term on the right-hand side clearly converges as $\epsilon \to 0^+$ for all $0<\alpha$, while the integral clearly converges as $\epsilon \to 0^+$ for all $\alpha<1$.  Thus, the integral $\int_1^2 \frac{\log x}{(x-1)^{\alpha}}\,dx$ converges only when $0<\alpha<1$ and diverges otherwise.

---

NOTE:

Since $\int_2^{\infty} \frac{\log x}{(x-1)^{\alpha}}\,dx$ converges only when $alpha >1$, the integral $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\log x}{(x-1)^{\alpha}}\,dx$ diverges for all $\alpha$.